# how can I read a zip file to stream?

Tags: vb.net

I have a method that gives a stream file and upload it to server.

I want read a zip file from my disk and put it into a stream file, then my method can upload it automatically.

I search too much but the results just helps me to read a text file to stream! just like this:

```
Dim fileReader As System.IO.StreamReader
fileReader =
My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileReader("C:\\testfile.txt")
Dim stringReader As String
stringReader = fileReader.ReadLine()
MsgBox("The first line of the file is " & stringReader)
```

but I want read a zip file to stream, not text file!

Comment: Zip file isn't a text file. Lines are "meaningless" in it, they are not strings, and are highly unlikely to print. So your code as it stands is totally unsuitable. Base64 encode decode is probably what you want to google, but your intent is far from clear.

Comment: Check this out: http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/, or google for other 3rd party zip libraries. Native .NET is limited when working with ZIP files, from what I remember. Correct me if I'm wrong and things have changed in newer versions of the framework.